# Netty - Find Channel ID

Tags: netty, channel, illegalstateexception

I just started working with Netty. I already have a server, and im writing code for a client.

In the client, i set a new PipelineFactory for the ClientBootstrap object with this code

```
    bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() 
    {
        public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() 
        {
            return Channels.pipeline(new ResponseHandler());
        }
    }
                                );
```

where ResponseHandler() is my class that extends SimpleChannelHandler.

Im looking to find the Channel ID. I did

```
 bootstrap.getPipeline().getChannel().getId();
```

but it throws IllelgalStateException and says i cant call getPipeline() because i have called setPipelineFactory(). What is the method to obtain the Channel ID ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you called connect? [Netty tutorial (3.5)](http://netty.io/3.5/guide/#start.9)

I think after connecting you can get the channel ID on all the methods of [SimpleChannelHandler (3.5)](http://netty.io/3.5/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/SimpleChannelHandler.html) with

```
ChannelEvent.getChannel().getId()
```

---

For Netty 4

given the ChannelHandlerContext object (variable name = ctx) it would be

```
ctx.channel().id()
```

Comment: @MouseEvent fixed, although latest stable release of Netty is now at the 4.x series.